# PHP 'add more' link with multiple category filtering

Tags: javascript, php

I want the user to be able to filter the items with more than one category selection.
At the moment, the user can select a category from a dropdown and see items only from that category. What I'd like to do is, on 'add more' button click, after more dropdown menus are added, let the user select more categories

not sure how to add the unique id for each category. any help is appreciated!

```
<script>
function addInput(divName, template){
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
      document.getElementById(template).appendChild(newdiv);
}
</script>
<div id="template">
    <select name="category">
        <?php 
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
            if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $name = $row['name'];                                                           

                    if($cat_id === $id) { 
                        echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
                    }else{ 
                        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
                    }
                }                                           
            }                                   
        ?>
    </select>                                           
</div>
<div id="add_more_cat"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="addInput('template', 'add_more_cat');">+ Add more</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set atribute for div.

```
<script>
function addInput(divName, template){
      var count=0;
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
      newdiv.setAttribute("elem_id_"+count,document.getElementById('category').value) ;
      document.getElementById(template).appendChild(newdiv);
      count++;
}
</script>
```

this didn't tested, but algorytm is that: [set new attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) for new divs. And then [get these attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp).

Comment: and how can I put each "elem_id_"+count later into the php query that displays the results?

Comment: You can send the elements with ajax, or send with url.

Comment: could you tell me how you do that?

Comment: @Gadgetster I wrote your [code](http://jsfiddle.net/mehmanbashirov/h2hmd/1/). But I didn't understand what are you trying.Do You need many selects? or divs?

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution.. use this javascript..

```
<script>
    function addInput(divName, template) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(template).appendChild(newdiv);

    var selectElements = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectElements.length; i++)
        selectElements[i].id = 'id-' + i;
        selectElements[i].name = 'select-' + i;


}
</script>
```

Comment: wasn't me.. how do I take the dropdown menu selection of each created id and place it in the query?

Comment: wait.. check the edit.. put `name attributes` as well... so you can get it through post...

Comment: could you show me how to pull out the attributes to be placed in a php query later?

Comment: put your select boxes in a `form`.. and just use `submit button` to post the data... simple as that

Comment: the select boxes are in a form, but i am not sure how to set up so that each dropdown box takes the selected id and passes it on

Comment: you will need to use `count of select tags` so you can post that count value also.. so you will come to know that how many select values are passed to the post page..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49774/discussion-between-gadgetster-and-nishant-solanki)

Comment: i get them to be posted in the url and i can echo the variables but i cannot seem to get them working with the query

Comment: than you must be missing something in your query.. please provide your query as well

Answer (score -1):

you need to add  fields for new category that you want to create and save it with ajax or submit , then repopulate your Input select box, Thats my understanding please explain your question that will be more help full

Comment: There are some nonsense people they have only this work, some terrorist kind of people , they dont know what they are doing, they are doing to full fill there desires :(